# Change Paypal Adaptive Payments login language

Tags: python, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

My website receives payments through paypal.
My users are complaining they only see the login screen in portuguese, which they not understand.
I've tried the solution proposed [here](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/forums/digital-goods/language-settings) (as the code below shows), but no luck so far.

Here's a little test I'm making:
The code below uses [paypalx](https://github.com/e-loue/python-paypalx), and is available as a [gist](https://gist.github.com/4298454)

```
from django.conf import settings
from paypalx import AdaptivePayments
from urllib import urlencode
from urllib2 import urlopen, Request
import logging

paypal = AdaptivePayments(settings.PAYPAL_API_USERNAME, 
    settings.PAYPAL_API_PASSWORD, 
    settings.PAYPAL_API_SIGNATURE, 
    settings.PAYPAL_API_APPLICATION_ID, 
    settings.PAYPAL_API_EMAIL, 
    sandbox=settings.PAYPAL_USE_SANDBOX)

receivers = []
receivers.append({'amount' : '10.00', 'email' : 'penepoleb@gmail.com'})
response = paypal.pay(
    actionType = 'PAY',
    cancelUrl = settings.PAYPAL_CANCEL_URL,
    currencyCode = 'USD',
    feesPayer = 'EACHRECEIVER',
    receiverList = { 'receiver': receivers},
    returnUrl = settings.PAYPAL_RETURN_URL,
    ipnNotificationUrl = settings.PAYPAL_IPNNOTIFY_URL,
    errorLanguage = "en_US"
)
paykey = response['payKey']
print('https://www.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/pay?paykey=%s&expType=light&country.x=us&locale=en_US&change_locale=1' % paykey)
```

Here's one such paykey generated with my paypal credentials: AP-2AG393088X128224K
Now, you can try to open the generated URL and see that it is in portuguese:
https://www.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/pay?paykey=AP-2AG393088X128224K&expType=light&country.x=us&locale=en_US&change_locale=1

But if you try a different paykey, then the locale parameters work
(I'm using the paykey I got from [this example](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/forums/digital-goods/language-settings): AP-7LB18162J0578713L)
If you go to the link below you'll see that it's in english.

https://www.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/pay?paykey=AP-7LB18162J0578713L&expType=light&country.x=us&locale=en_US&change_locale=1

What do I need to do to show users a login page in english?

Comment: May be because you have a PayPal in Portuguese? Have you checked for addition settings in Paypal?

Comment: I'm brazilian, so I have a brazilian Paypal account. Sure it must have something to do with that. But I already set every language settings on Paypal to english. Now when I logon to paypal, I see all the menus in english. But my application still "generates paykeys in portuguese". If there's a config for this, I'd like to know where it is...

Comment: Wait a minute, now that the paykey expired, the error page is being displayed in english. But when the paykey is valid, it was being showed in portuguese. This looks like a bug in Paypal :-(

Comment: Here's a screenshot as evidence: (when I acessed with a still valid paykey at: https://www.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/pay?paykey=AP-6NV04939765297103&expType=light&country.x=us&locale=en_US&change_locale=1) - see http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2683925/paypal_portuguese.png

Answer (score 1):

Please check [this](http://www.tipsandtricks-hq.com/forum/topic/paypal-link-redirecting-to-wrong-language) post - it seems to refer to the same problem you have.

Thanks,

Arthur

Comment: You may also want to check this related post: http://www.tipsandtricks-hq.com/forum/topic/how-to-send-buyers-to-english-url-version-of-paypal-checkout-page

Answer (score 0):

Following the tip by @casals, I found out that there's another paypal URL that I can use.

[1] - https://www.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/pay?paykey=...

[2] - https://www.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_ap-payment&paykey=...

I was using [1] inside an iframe.

Now I'm using [2] with a browser redirect. Redirecting to [2] will make paypal present the login page in english, as desired.

This changes the payment experience a little bit - the user actually has to leave my site and then is redirected back to it. But that's fine, I think users actually prefer it this way because they can see Paypal's url when they type their credentials.

I still believe the current behaviour with [1] is a bug in paypal.

My application - http://www.freedomsponsors.org - is open source on Github and you can see the piece of changed code [here](https://github.com/freedomsponsors/www.freedomsponsors.org/blob/54aa5a5ce06561b6d1d1da4552f9ad50cb6b33a3/djangoproject/core/views/paypal_views.py))